# Just how good is Android's ContactsContract.PhoneLookup class?

Tags: android, contactscontract

Phone numbers can be expressed lots of different ways:

- 555-555-5555
- 1-555-555-5555
- +1-555-555-5555

Are all the same number, just expressed differently. [Android's ContactsContract.PhoneLookup class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) Is designed to solve this problem. I'm about to run this through some tests and post the results, but I figured it would be worth making a question to see if anyone else had some experience with this and knows the answer. I could save a ton of headaches by not needing to filter out the +1 and other extraneous symbols before the number if I can count on this PhoneLookup class to do its job for the users. Can anyone testify in support of it?

Thanks. If I don't hear back from anyone I will run some tests and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a quick application to test this, found that the class can account for every variation of a phone number:

- +15555555
- 15555555
- 5555555

Including hyphens (-) as well. Hope this save someone time in the future.